# Linux Kernel / Android Custom Device / Platform Information Needed

Tags: android, embedded, embedded-linux

I am working on a new device that is to support Android that is ARM SOC based. My background is a Linux kernel developer and I have built u-boot and the latest kernel (from kernel.org) along with a minimum root file system which all comes up nicely.

My question is how might I make a specific 'platform' to select in the Android build process? There does not seem to be a lot of information on this subject or it is obfuscated somehow. A how-to guide for building for a custom device would be a great help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what kernel your using but Android uses a modified kernel, you'll want to start with that if you haven't rather than the 'stock' kernel source at https://android.googlesource.com/.

I'd recommend looking at the CyangenMod project (http://www.cyanogenmod.com/). It is structured for supporting many different devices, not that the 'raw' source from google isn't, but cyanogen supports many more devices out of the box and is constantly getting new devices.  Their irc channel and dev forums are also probably your best resource for questions on adding new device support.

There is a basic wiki on building cyanogen here: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Compile_CyanogenMod_for_Passion

You can see after pulling the source that there are separate projects for each device, you'll be adding your own, maybe using one as a basis depending on the similarities in your dev board / SoC with the already available devices.  Either way you can use their structure as a framework for your device. (there is a sample in the device directory)

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest starting with a build for a similar device rather than from scratch; however if it's something really more eval-board-like than product-like it might make sense to look at projects for that rather than (or in addition to) CM, for example android on beagle board, etc.

Comment: We are using the android kernel from there. Our product is ARM based with three different platforms using Samsung, Telechips, and Freescale SOC's. This is why we want to be able to have configurations specific to our hardware and build Android for them. It's still not clear how we get the Android SDK to recognize a custom platform device from the Android Linux kernel